# preciso mostrar a chave quando os valores forem todos maiores que 7

Tags: python

só consegui fazer quando a média é maior de 7 mas quero que todos os valores sejam maiores de 7.
o certo seria sair "Kayan, Rodrigo" mas ta saindo "Kayan, Luis Carlos, Rodrigo"

```
def aprovados(D):
  for alunos, notas in D.items():
    x = sum(D[alunos])/3
    if x >= 7:
      print(alunos)

D = {"Kayan" : (7.5,8.0,7.0),
     "Kevin" : (5.5,6.5,8.0),
     "Luis Carlos" : (8.5,6.5,7.0),
     "Rodrigo" : (7.5,8.5,9.0)}

aprovados(D)
```

Answer (score -1):

Você vai precisar inserir uma variável booleana (que retorna `True` ou `False`) onde em cada loop é atribuido o valor `True`. Então você cria um loop "aninhado" dentro loop já existente que verifica cada nota para ver se é `>= 7`. Caso alguma das notas não forem, a variável se tornará `False`, irá encerrar o loop´e irá para o próximo aluno. Caso contrário, o booleano continuará verdadeiro e irá acionar o "if statement" que imprime o nome do aluno:

```
for aluno, notas in D.items():
    esta_aprovado = True
    for nota in notas:
        if nota < 7:
            esta_aprovado = False
            break
    if esta_aprovado:
        print(aluno)
```

Referências:

https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements

https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques

Comment: eu consegui resolver assim `def aprovados(D):
  for alunos, notas in D.items():
    x = 0
    for nota in notas:
      if nota >= 7:
        x += 1
        if x == 3:
          print(alunos)

D = {"Kayan" : (7.5,8.0,7.0),
     "Kevin" : (5.5,6.5,8.0),
     "Luis Carlos" : (8.5,6.5,7.0),
     "Rodrigo" : (7.5,8.5,9.0)}

aprovados(D)`

Answer (score -2):

Oi!

Está exibindo os três, pois a lógica que vc está fazendo é somar os valores e dividir por três - daí, se esse resultado for maior do que 7, ele printa. Vc precisa mudar essa lógica, porque ele não tem uma validação para cada elemento dentro de cada aluno da lista.
Espero ter ajudado!